# Retrieving command line history

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-11.04

I use ubuntu 11.04, and the question must be common to any bash shell. Pressing the up arrow key on your terminal will retrieve the previous command you had executed at your terminal.

My question is where(in which file) will all these command history be stored? Can I read that file?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

the history filename was stored in variable :  $HISTFILE

```
echo  $HISTFILE
```

will give you the right file.

**Usually** in bash it would be ~/.bash_history, however it could be changed by configuration.

also notice that sometimes the very last commands is not stored in that file. running

```
history -a
```

will persistent.

```
history -r
```

will clean those command not yet written to  the file.

Answer (score 15):

For bash, it is by default in `~/.bash_history` (check the `HISTFILE` environment variable if it isn't). You can directly `cat` the file or use the `history` command.

Comment: you can also try ```history > ouputfile.txt``` to save the contents to a file.